# error : General error: 1364 Field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'AccountNumber' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `accounts` (`AccountClass`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2019-10-23 08:58:29, 2019-10-23
>   08:58:29))

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Accounts;
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        return view ('upload');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){


        $file = $request->file('upload-file');
        $csvData = file_get_contents($file);

        $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));

        $header = array_shift($rows);
//    dd($header);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $row = array_combine($header, $row);
            Accounts::create([
                'AccountClass' => $row['Classe'],
                'AccountNumber' => $row['Compte'],
                'AccountDesc' => $row['Desc'],
                'active' => 1,
            ]);
        }


    }

}
```

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('AccountClass');
            $table->integer('AccountNumber');
            $table->string('AccountDesc');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('accounts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your Accounts model it's fillable.

**Accounts.php** model

```
class Accounts extends Model
{    
     protected $fillable = [
        'AccountClass', 'AccountNumber', 'AccountDesc',
    ];  
}
```

If you're not passing value while insert make default value as `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

In your migration you can do this to make the column nullable:

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('AccountNumber')->nullable();
        }); 
}
```

`->nullable()` Designate that the column allows NULL values

Answer (score 1):

1. Rollback CreateAccountsTable migration file.
2. Edit this migration file and replace

```
$table->integer('AccountNumber');
```

with

```
$table->integer('AccountNumber')->default();
```

3. Migrate the migration file and test it again.